# Writing to a file horizontally

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, printf

I have a script that I want to run and then write the output to a file in a specific format
Currently when I run the script and direct it to standard output it gives it to me in the format I want. The issue is when I try to send it to a file it loses the formatting and just gives me the output in the file on the same line
Here is the output that I want written in this specific way to the file:
[image: Wanted output]
and here is what it actually gives me when I write it to a file
[image: Actual output]
Here is my code for this

```
printf "%s\n" "==================" >> test
printf "%s\n" "Disk Space. Look for /" >> test
printf "%s\n" "==================" >> test
printf "%s\n" $(df | grep '/dev/') >> test 
printf "%s\n" "==================" >> test
```

How I can the output in the file to look like the output in the command line.

Edit: I am running this through plink (putty command line) and these commands are in my command file that I am using.

Comment: Your code is fine for apps that run on Linux, but it looks like you want the file to be used on Windows (your screenshot shows Notepad). Is that correct?

Comment: sorry, I should have added I am running this through plink (putty command line) from a linux box and the commands are just the command file I am using to pass the commands to the linux box

Comment: If you want to use your files on Windows, replace `\n` with `\r\n`, as that is the default end-of-line marker there. Or simply use literally any other editor than notepad, as that seems to be the only program that still has trouble with this. Notepad++ seems to be a favorite among many, though wordpad.exe also works and comes preinstalled with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, it seems you're viewing the file in Windows's Notepad. It only recognizes Windows-style line-endings (CR+LF), and shows files with Unix-style line-endings just like that, on a single line.

You can change `\n` to `\r\n` in your `printf` to output Windows-style line-endings instead.

Comment: Actually this answered my question perfectly. Maybe a bit more detail would have been nice but it really does though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run your file through `unix2dos` (the opposite of `dos2unix`, but pulling from the same `dos2unix-*` rpm), then sending your file to your destination. This should get your file to play nice in Windows.